# How can I implement a bottom sheet above a tabbar in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabbar, bottom-sheet

I'm working on an iOS app, and I'd like to implement a bottom sheet that appears above the TabBar.

I would like to get the appearance as in the image.

[image]

I appreciate any guidance on how to achieve this user interface behavior. Thank you!

I've explored various SwiftUI layouts and gestures, but I'm unsure how to make the bottom sheet overlap the TabBar.

When trying to call:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var isBottomSheetPresented = false

var body: some View {
    TabView {
    // ...
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isBottomSheetPresented) {
        //....
    }
}
```

still the sheet overlaps the tabbar, it's above it.

Comment: You can clearly see that the sheet is showing over the mapview and not the tabview so add it over that.

Comment: Similar was also asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74857596/how-can-i-make-a-bottom-sheet-appear-behind-a-tabview and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75532864/present-a-view-modally-below-the-tabview-in-swiftui?rq=1